# ESP32 as an end device rule in openthread network

Tags: esp32, openthread

As we know in a openthread network, some devices are end device and some of them are boarder router. My question is: Is it possible to a Wi-Fi enabled device like ESP32 acts as an end device instead of boarder router?

Answer (score 1):

A Thread device can operate in an end device role, regardless of what other network interfaces it supports. A device can simply operate as a host on multiple network interfaces.